# Karaf 4.1 - How to add DynamicImport-Package tag within a third party osgi jar bundle?

Tags: osgi, classloader, shiro, apache-karaf, karaf

I have a problem in the execution of a own bundle within Karaf 4.1, I am using Shiro for to persist users sessions, but when I recover the saved session, I have got an exception as:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.twim.models.User
> ```
>
> > ```
> > at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:?]
> >     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:?]
> >     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:?]
> >     at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.doImplicitBootDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1782) ~[?:?]
> >     at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchDynamicImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1717) ~[?:?]
> >     at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1552) ~[?:?]
> >     at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79) ~[?:?]
> > ```

I understand the problem in my case Shiro is executing a (cast) deserializing the persisted session object but within Shiro's ClassLoader there is no my class io.twim.models.User. My karaf instance have installed this bundles:

> ```
> karaf@twim()> list
> START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
> ID │ State  │ Lvl │ Version             │ Name
> ───┼────────┼─────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 51 │ Active │  80 │ 3.1.0               │ DataStax Java Driver for Apache Cassandra - Core
> 52 │ Active │  80 │ 19.0.0              │ Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java
> 73 │ Active │  50 │ 2.16.1              │ camel-blueprint
> 83 │ Active │  80 │ 1.3.0               │ Apache Shiro :: Core
> 86 │ Active │  80 │ 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT      │ twim-cache :: Distributed cache for TWIM
> 87 │ Active │  80 │ 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT      │ twim-cassandra :: Implementation Cassandra to TWIM
> 88 │ Active │  80 │ 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT      │ twim-common :: Bundle utility for all models, utilities, constants
> 89 │ Active │  80 │ 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT      │ twim-core-model :: Bundle utility for all models used in TWIM
> 90 │ Active │  80 │ 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT      │ twim-db :: Utilitaries to persitence into TWIM
> 91 │ Active │  80 │ 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT      │ twim-jaas :: JAAS authentication module for TWIM
> ```

I need to add the tag DynamicImport-Package at the bundle 83:

> ```
> 83 │ Active │  80 │ 1.3.0               │ Apache Shiro :: Core
> ```

Executing *dynamic-import* command within karaf, I have fixed this problem:

> ```
> karaf@twim()> dynamic-import 83
> ```

But I would like to do this automatically in my feature installer, adding this tag *DynamicImport-Package: io.twim.models*, now I have my features.xml like this:

```
<feature name="twim-auth" version="${project.version}">
    <feature>twim-cassandra</feature>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.shiro/shiro-core/1.3.0</bundle>

    <bundle>mvn:io.twim/twim-core-model/${project.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:io.twim/twim-jaas/${project.version}</bundle>
</feature>
```

How can I do this within my features.xml?

Answer (score 1):

The [wrap protocol](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxurl/Wrap+Protocol) can be used to build osgi bundle on-the-fly from a jar. You can probably use it to add some instructions to an existant bundle, but I never used it this way. Try something like this :

```
<bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.shiro/shiro-core/1.3.0$DynamicImport-Package=io.twim.models</bundle>
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried some variations of wrap protocol within of my features.xml, but nothing works. I've seen in the source of karaf, how to do the dynamic-import command (https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/bundle/core/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/bundle/core/internal/BundleServiceImpl.java#L229), but I don't know what is the best way to do it.

Comment: Can you show us the manifest that is generated by the wrap protocol, and the exact string you used in feature ? You can use the webconsole to display the manifest.

Comment: There are some differences between putting the tag **DynamicImport-Package=io.twim.models** [1] like you suggested  and activate **dynamic-import 84** [2] from karaf. You can check in this links the differences: [1]: https://gist.github.com/christmo/0b499be96393ad784585350aeaa4d8ae#file-1st-from-installer-mf-L3           [2]: https://gist.github.com/christmo/0b499be96393ad784585350aeaa4d8ae#file-2nd-shiro-dynamic-import-mf-L74

Comment: I put in my feature.xml this: <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.shiro/shiro-core/1.3.0$DynamicImport-Package=io.twim.models</bundle> and the result was this manifest https://gist.github.com/christmo/0b499be96393ad784585350aeaa4d8ae#file-1st-from-installer-mf-L3, but if I want to activate with the command **> dynamic-import 84** , I will get this error: Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Invalid syntax for instruction [DynamicImport-Package=io.twim.models$Bundle-UpdateLocation=wrap:mvn:org.apache.shiro/shiro-core/1.3.0$DynamicImport-Package=io.twim.models]. Take a look at

Comment: If the bundle location is already "wrapped" it is not surprising that it is not working. What is more surprising is that it is not working through the features xml. Have you tried to set ``DynamicImport-Package=*&overwrite=merge`` as it is done with the "dynamic-import" command ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally!, I have figured out the problem thanks to @alexandre-cartapanis only was necessary a correction, putting this it works perfectly:

```
<bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.shiro/shiro-core/1.3.0/$DynamicImport-Package=io.twim.models&amp;overwrite=merge</bundle>
```

Here in ["Wrap deployer"](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-3.0.x/) section there is more explanation.